# I seem to have discovered a new converging series for $\pi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, convergence-divergence, pi

Recently, I was experimenting with formulas involving circles and convergent series and came across a new type of series which seems to converge to $\pi$  extremely fast. I have yet to see this anywhere so I was curious to see if it is completely unique or if it already exists. In the case that is unique, would it be safe for me to share it here and would it even be considered a significant find?

Edit: I have inserted my series below, feel free to check if it works

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{2}\left ( 1000^{1000n} \right )!\left \{ \sin\left [ \frac{360}{\left ( 1000^{1000n} \right )!} \right ] \right \}=\pi
$$

Comment: Unless you do "share" it, how can we tell if it's of any interest?

Comment: Well, at some point you will probably _have_ to share it if you want anyone to help you check whether your calculations are correct and whether it is a significant find.

Comment: This is not a question about mathematics, but about the functioning of the site. As such, it does not belong in the main site, but in meta.

Comment: FWIW, every part of this question except "would it be safe to share here" would be misplaced on meta.

Comment: It sounds significant and interesting, but we'd have to see it to know for sure. For example, the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_n$ where $a_1 = \pi$ and $a_n = 0$ for $n \ge 2$ converges to $\pi$ extremely fast, but isn't interesting. Anyway, I think you should share it, and see what other people think. Worst case scenario: someone points out a flaw or points out that it's been discovered before, in which case, you don't lose anything. Best case scenario: you discovered something which is both new and interesting, and you can get it published somewhere.

Comment: Are you measuring angles in *degrees*?

Comment: yes. Wouldn't make sense to use radians in a series-defining pi.

Comment: Well if you're willing to use trigonometric functions in your series for $ \pi $, I've got a better series for you: $ \pi = 2 \sin^ {-1} (1) $.

Comment: If I'm reading the series correctly, each **term** is approximately $\pi$ so the series diverges.

Comment: I concur with Lord Shark: $\sin\theta\approx \theta$ for small angles.

Comment: How did you arrive at this series? It is always helpful to show your work here.

Answer (score 7):

This has the form $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{m_n}2\left(\sin\frac{360^\circ}{m_n}\right)$$
where $m_n\to \infty$. But
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac m2\left(\sin\frac{360^\circ}m\right)=\pi$$
so your series diverges.

Also I am not aware of any method of numerically calculating $\sin x^\circ$
which doesn't require knowledge of $\pi$ to a similar accurracy.